# When does ReactJS Native proxy to your server, and how do you get it to run on an iOS device for real, independently of the server?

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs-native

I ran a fledgling ReactJS Native / iOS app under development from the simulator, and noticed that when I tested it on my iPhone, it immediately crashed because the device couldn't talk to its own 127.0.0.1:8081. (The solution to this was to change a setting so it referred to my machine's IP.)

When does ReactJS Native proxy to your server, and how (some more formal app installation process?) do you get it to run on an iOS device for real, independently of your development box acting as a server?